# Firestore data are duplicating whenever i a navigate to another route and return

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

So I have a problem and I am really stuck . I have an angular application that uses firestore as a backend . I have a service that retreive data from the firestore but when i display them for example in my home page .when i navigate to another page and return the data will be duplicated (just in the view not in the firestore) . below is my hom component and my event service .

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  auth: AuthenticationService;
  user ;
  events: Evenement[];
  subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(auth: AuthenticationService, private eventService: EvenmentService, private attendService: AttendingService, private router: Router) {
    this.auth = auth ;
    this.user = auth.user$.subscribe( (user) => {
    this.user = user;
  });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.subscription =   this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('loaded');
      this.events = res;
    }, (error1 => console.log(error1)));

  }




  ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();

  }

}
```

this is the event service

```
@Injectable()
export class EvenmentService implements OnInit {


  eventsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Evenement>;
  events: Observable<Evenement[]>;
  eventDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Evenement>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore, private router: Router) {
    // this.events = this.afs.collection('events').valueChanges();
    this.eventsCollection = this.afs.collection('events', ref => ref.orderBy('title', 'asc'));

    this.events = this.eventsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Evenement;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    });
  }

  getEvents() {
    return this.events;
  }

  addEvent(event: Evenement) {
    this.eventsCollection.add(event).then(() => {
      console.log('event added success');
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  deleteEvent(event: Evenement) {
    this.eventDoc = this.afs.doc(`events/${event.id}`);
    this.eventDoc.valueChanges().subscribe(value => console.log(value));

    this.eventDoc.delete().then(() => {
      console.log('event deleted with succes');
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }







}
```

home.html

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events" class="card border-dark mb-3" style="width: 318px;box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px grey;">
  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: white">Date : {{event.date.day}}-{{event.date.month}}-{{event.date.year}} | Available places : {{ event.nbreDePlace - event.reserved}}</div>
  <div class="card-body text-dark">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{event.title}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{event.description}}</p>
  </div>

  <div class="card-footer"style="background-color: white" >
      <div *ngIf="already(event)" style="color: red;">you already subscribed to this event</div>
    <button  class="btn btn-default" (click)="attend(event)" [disabled]="!(event.reserved< event.nbreDePlace) || already(event)">Subscribe</button>  </div>
    <button class="btn " style="background-color: skyblue" (click)="detail(event)">view Details</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you call `this.eventsCollection.snapshotChanges()` you register a new observer for changes to the collection. Since you never remove this observer, the second time you construct a `EvenmentService` it will register a second observer.

To prevent this you will either need to [detach the observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) when the service goes out of scope, or you'll need to track if the observer is already attached when constructing a new service.

Which of these is best depends on the type of object this is: for singletons you typically want to detect if you've already registered the observer, since they can maintain state. For objects whose lifecycle is associated with screens/views of your app, you'll usually want to detach the observer(s) in the lifecycle event of your framework that fires when the screen/view disappears.

Comment: thank you for your answer it very helpfull but can you tell me how can I check if I already registred the observer ?

Comment: You will need to keep track of that yourself, by keeping the handle of the observer somewhere. In the regular JavaScript SDK, you do that by calling `ref.off(handleOfObserver)` or `ref.off()` (which removes all observers from that ref). I'm not too well phrased in AngularFire2, but it seems an `unsubscribe` might be what's needed there.